# Enemy follow player, rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, model, rotation, blender

I created Enemy that follow Player and rotate too. My problem is that my spaceship model rotation is diffrent than while i was making it with Blender.
This is how Enemy follow and how ship look like with rotation X:0 Y:0 Z: 0
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLbaz.png
In Blender, everything is fine, nothing wrong with rotation etc.
This is Enemy script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

        public static float health;
        private float reloadTime;

        public Rigidbody laser;
        public GameObject explo;
        public Transform playerShip;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
                health = 20.0f;
                reloadTime = 0.3f;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

                //transform.LookAt(playerShip.transform.position);
                Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerShip.transform.position - this.transform.position);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * 2);
                transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 2 * Time.deltaTime);

                reloadTime -= Time.deltaTime;

                if(reloadTime <= 0f)
                {
                        Rigidbody clone = Instantiate(laser, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
                        clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, 80);
                        Destroy(clone.gameObject, 3);
                        reloadTime = 0.3f;
                }

                if(health <= 0f)
                {
                        GameObject exp = Instantiate(explo, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                        Destroy(this.gameObject);
                        Destroy(exp.gameObject, 1.5f);
                }
        }
}
```

What can be wrong with this rotations?

How can I change rotation in this code so X will be always 270?

```
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerShip.transform.position - this.transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * 2);
```

Comment: Post your code on here, not on a third party site.

Comment: Not only that, post what *specifically* isn't working. `What can be wrong with this rotations?` does not at all clarify what your specific issue is.

Comment: I'm asking about that weird model position. Why it's not like it should (on image, ship at the right is fine but with X rotation = 270).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Just had to do this.:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-FixZAxisIsUp.html